# Java Scheduler Quartz Cron Trigger Time Setting

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, crontrigger, cronexpression

I am using Quartz for Scheduling my job in java. I have used "CronTrigger" for setting my time.
I want to fire my Job each day at 11:55 Pm in night. What should i write in the setCronExpression(" ") for having my Job Done. .??

What i thought of the Code is:---

```
CronTrigger trigger = new CronTrigger();
trigger.setName("runMeJob");
trigger.setCronExpression("0 55 23 * * ?");
```

Is the above code correct or should i do some modifications in it????

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It would be: **0 55 23 1/1 * ? ***

There is a nice website exactly for your case: [CronMaker](http://www.cronmaker.com/)

> CronMaker is a utility which helps you to build cron expressions.
>   CronMaker uses Quartz open source scheduler. Generated expressions are
>   based on Quartz cron format.